# Error in Fragment (inflate):Unable to resume activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

when the fragment is called it execute onCreateView, but crash on the return inflate...
This fragment is called by a function (in another fragment) that register data on firebase. When i start the app and this fragment (waiting) is called, the run log says that i am in the waiting fragment, but there are messages of activity on firebase. Can be the error?
This is the Fragment:

```
class waiting : Fragment() {
    var queue : RequestQueue? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_waiting, container, false)
    }
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        want_to_play()
        //  Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({check()},Conf.pollingPeriod)
    }

    fun want_to_play() {
        
        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        val stringRequest = StringRequest(
            Request.Method.GET, url + "NEWGAME" + "/" + Conf.myid,
            { response ->
                // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                val reply = JSONObject(response.toString())
                val error = reply!!.getBoolean("error")
                if (error) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "error:"+reply.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
                else {
                    val who = reply!!.getInt("who")
                    Conf.myid = who
                   
                    val msg = reply!!.getString(("msg"))
                    if(msg == "WAIT"){ 
                        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({check()}, Conf.pollingPeriod)
                    }

                }
            },
            { error: VolleyError? ->
                Log.i("info", "Polling: " + error.toString())
            })
        // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue?.add(stringRequest)
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        return
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        return
    }

    fun check() {
        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        val stringRequest = StringRequest(
            Request.Method.GET, url + "WAITING" + "/" + Conf.myid,
            { response ->
                // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                val reply = JSONObject(response.toString())
                val msg = reply!!.getString(("msg"))

                //No players yet, keep polling...
                if (msg != "GAMECREATED"){
                    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({check()},Conf.pollingPeriod)
                } else //Ho trovato un player
                {
                    Conf.other = reply!!.getInt("who")
                    findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_waiting_to_onlineFragment)


                }
            },
            { error: VolleyError? ->
                Log.i("info", "Polling: " + error.toString())
            })
        // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue?.add(stringRequest)
    }
}
```

this is the error:

```
Process: com.example.ilmiogioco, PID: 10680
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.ilmiogioco/com.example.ilmiogioco.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0c0033
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4205)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4237)
    at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:52)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0c0033
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:237)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2281)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1175)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
    at com.example.ilmiogioco.waiting.onCreateView(waiting.kt:35)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2963)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:518)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2106)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:3036)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.resume(FragmentStateManager.java:607)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:306)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:112)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1647)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3128)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchResume(FragmentManager.java:3086)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchResume(FragmentController.java:273)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onResumeFragments(FragmentActivity.java:458)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onPostResume(FragmentActivity.java:447)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onPostResume(AppCompatActivity.java:240)
    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7964)
```

Comment: Which specific folder is your `fragment_waiting.xml` layout file in?

Comment: As @Mike M. commented, the layout resource file `fragment_waiting.xml` isn't found by the build system, and hence it is throwing a `ResourceNotFoundException`. Make sure that all layout resource files are in the `<project_name>/app/src/main/res/layout` folder.

Comment: Thanks. The same fragment with position land was in different folder.